# How can we match string pattern like aa12ss9098 kind of registration number?

Tags: ios, swift, regex

I am trying to match a string pattern that contains two characters, two numeric values , two characters and four numeric values. Can some please help me out

EG:- AP04ST9099

Below is the code I am trying for this

`^\\[a-z]{2}-\\d{2}-\\[a-z]{2}-\\d{4}$`

Comment: Hi there. What have your tried so far?

Comment: Hi, I was trying this  "^\\[a-z]-\\d{3}-\\[a-z]-\\d{3}$"

Comment: I'm not great at swift, but at first glance you have capital letters in the string you are trying to match, yet the regex is only testing for lower case eg [a-z] would need to be  [A-Z]

Comment: I have tried with small letters too. But It's not matching

Comment: there bunch of dashes in there as well? The first digit class you are trying to match 3 but you only have digits in the input string. The last digit class you are trying to match 3 but you have 4....

Comment: The perl equivalent to match your input would be [A-Z]{2}\d{2}[A-Z]{2}\d{4}

Comment: What are the requirements? Only lowercase letters? Only uppercase letters? Or both? Match a substring or the entire string?

Answer (score 0):

Please find below regex with solution.

```
extension String {
    func matches(_ regex: String) -> Bool {
        return self.range(of: regex, options: .regularExpression, range: nil, locale: nil) != nil
    }
}


"AP04ST9099".matches("^[A-Za-z]{2}\\d{2}[A-Za-z]{2}\\d{4}$")//true
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5
You can create a regular expression and confirm the string with regular expression. 
Regular expression:

```
func isValidValue(passedValue: String) -> Bool {
  let valueRegEx = "^[A-Z]{2}+[0-9]{2}+[A-Z]{2}+[0-9]{4}"

  let valueTest = NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@", valueRegEx)

  return valueTest.evaluate(with: passedValue)
}

print(isValidValue(passedValue: "AP04ST9099"))
```

Answer (score 0):

Sorter one:

```
func isValidValue(passedValue: String) -> Bool {

    return NSPredicate(format:"SELF MATCHES %@","^[A-Z]{2}+[0-9]{2}+[A-Z]{2}+[0-9]{4}" ).evaluate(with: passedValue)
}

print(isValidValue(passedValue: "AP04ST9099"))
```